# navigationSplitViewColumnWidth for MacOS Ventura bug

Tags: xcode, macos, swiftui, macos-ventura

I was working on an app for macOS 12 but as Ventura came in, I wanted to upgrade to it and so get an app for macOS 13. I had to remove every single `NavigationView` as they are now deprecated, and replace them with `NavigationSplitView` or `NavigationStack`. Before adding it to my app, I tried using it on a POC and it did not went as I wanted too.

I am trying to get a `NavigationSplitView` with three columns (sidebar, content, detail) and tried to change the width of each columns, but it's half working. I did two buttons, one that makes the column bigger by 10 and on that makes it smaller by 10. As you can see if you try it, the width change is only working when I make the column bigger...

It is as simple as that :

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var visibility: NavigationSplitViewVisibility = .all
    @State var columnWidth: CGFloat = 200
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationSplitView(columnVisibility: $visibility) {
            Text("Sidebar")
        } content: {
            Text("Content")
                .navigationSplitViewColumnWidth(columnWidth)
        } detail: {
            Button {
                columnWidth += 10
                print(columnWidth)
            } label: { Text("Bigger") }
            Button {
                columnWidth -= 10
                print(columnWidth)
            } label: { Text("Smaller") }
        }
    }
}
```

**For info:** Changing the column that gets edited & removing or changing the `NavigationSplitViewVisibility` doesn't change anything. Also it seems like there is a minimalWidth but I can't really find it.

Comment: That is just for the navigation split view's column ... if you want to control the size of the window, then set `ContentView().frame(minWidth: 200)`

Comment: As I said @user1046037 , I indeed want to change the **columns** width and not the **window** width.

Comment: NavigationSplitViewVisibility.detailOnly is equally as useless. Hopefully, behind the scenes, it's trying to set the column width to 0, and failing, and will get fixed.

Comment: `.detailOnly` or `.all` is properly working for me @Drew .
Its goal isn't to enable / disable the sidebar but just to show or not show it by default when the user opens the app. It's like a preference setting .

Comment: I have exactly the same problem right now... Did you find a solution? Or is there just something like an HSplitView existing for iOS?

Comment: I have a similar problem on iPad. Setting anything with `navigationSplitViewColumnWidth` seems to have no effect whatsoever on the content or details columns. It does work, however, for the sidebar column.